# How do I get Activity Indicator on WkWebView Programmatically in Swift?

Tags: swift, wkwebview

Does anyone know how to get an Activity Indicator to pop up and then disappear on a WKWebView(done programmatically). I have tried other's methods but either ran into errors or didn't have the Activity Indicator show up at all.

My code for loading the WKWebView:

```
 var webView : WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

            let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
            webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
            view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

            self.webView.load(NSURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!) as URLRequest);
    }
```

Could I possibly send the activity indicator to a UIAlertController or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

at **class level** declare this property:

`let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)`.

In **viewDidLoad** add:

`indicator.center = webView.center
indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
webView.addSubview(indicator)`

**To use**

`indicator.startAnimating()` or `indicator.stopAnimating()` to show / hide it

Answer (score 0):

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    yourActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    //or what you want

}
```

Remember: Set delegate!

Hint: you can set also this value:

```
color: UIColor;
transparent: bool; 
bigSize: bool
```